# Match HTML Table Data text using CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to highlight some text in a table that isn't always present.

Grabbing the selector in chrome looks like this.

```
#post-325351 > td.media.column-media > strong:nth-child(15)
```

Here is the Element

```
<strong>Comments: </strong>
```

So whenever the `Comments:`  element is present, I'd like to highlight the word **Comments:** using my Stylus extension.

So I've tried using the nth-child selector, but that appears to change depending on the data presented, so I can't use that. The only thing I can think of is to match the `Comments:` text somehow, but can't figure out if it's possible with pure CSS.

Can this be done?

This screenshot shows that different elements can be present or absent.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju5Ms.png

Comment: When it's NOT present, the whole element is removed from DOM or just the content disappeared like this: `<strong></strong>` ?

Comment: It seems the entire reference is gone. I'm adding a screenshot to my post to hopefully explain better.

Comment: Id say you need JS for this. You ca not target elements by content alone in CSS